# Interface and interpreted language

Tags: php, interface, interpreter

I'm discovering Php and it's Oop implementation and wondering if there is really an practical utility of using Interfaces when we use a non compiled language and when errors can only be discovered at execution time. **Am in missing someting?**. Another point is that I didn't find any extension or plugin for editor or Ide which forced implementing the Interface when creating a class which is for me the essential point because Interface are really useful when working with others and functionals requirements. So that make me thinking that we need to know the contracts of the Interfaces before using them..
I didn't find any satisfying reading about these question and hope someone would give me some clues...

Comment: From my experiences, interfaces are only useful if you plan to have multiple classes re-using the same methods but using a completely different logic in these methods. Imagine a database connector. The logic in the methods are different if you interface MySQL, PGSQL, etc... In that case it makes sense to use interfaces. 
Also, IDEs do generate interface's methods automatically. PHPStorm for example does it automatically if configured.

Comment: Take a look at the 1st user note at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 0):

As my Questioning were on the way I can be sure of following the contract implied by an Interface I had a look on the differents Ide or extension (I'm using mainly vscode)and now what I understand is I rely on their functionalitie about continuous code validation. For example Dev Sense PHP tools for Vs Code do the job but normal Php Intelliphense doesn't.
If I don't use an Ide or extension with this code validation I will have executing time errors if I fail to execute the whole Interface contract.